# Replace elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Suppose that I have a list:

```
G = {{{a, c}, {a, c, x}}, {{c, e}, {c, e, x}}, {{e, f}, {a, e, f}}, 
     {{f, g}, {a, f, g}}, {{g, a}, {a, f, g}}, {{a, c, x}, {a, c}}, 
     {{a, c, x}, {a, e, x}}, {{a, c, x}, {c, e, x}}, {{a, e, f}, {e, f}}, 
     {{a, e, f}, {a, e, x}}, {{a, e, f}, {a, f, g}}, {{a, e, x}, {a, c, x}}, 
     {{a, e, x}, {a, e, f}}, {{a, e, x}, {c, e, x}}, {{a, f, g}, {f, g}}, 
     {{a, f, g}, {g, a}}, {{a, f, g}, {a, e, f}}, {{c, e, x}, {c, e}}, 
     {{c, e, x}, {a, c, x}}, {{c, e, x}, {a, e, x}}}
```

in which each element of `G` is an ordered pair `{A,B}`, where `A` and `B` are sets. I would like to convert the elements `A` and `B` into the numbers such as `{a, c} -> 1`, `{c, e} -> 2`, ..., `{a, c, x} -> 10`. I also need to change all of `{c, e}` in `G` into `2`. How can I do this? I try to use `Replace` but it doesn't work.

Comment: just curious: why is `{a,c,x}->10`? Maybe you could implement something smarter to replace (but I cannot see a pattern). Also, you should try to avoid single, capitalized letters as variable names (to avoid conflicts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReplaceRepeated` is probably what you want. Something like:

```
G //. {{a, c} -> 1, {a, c, x} -> 2}
```

//. is the shortcut for this. `ReplaceAll` probably also works:

```
G /. {{a, c} -> 1, {a, c, x} -> 2}
```